# Running Complexity of Insertion Sort

Tags: c, big-o, insertion-sort

In a book about data structure and algorithms, there is the following implementation of the insertion sort:

```
int insertionSort(void *data, int size, int esize, int(*compare)(const void *key1, const void *key2)){

    int i,j; 
    void *key,

    char *a = data;

    key = (char *) malloc(esize);

    if(key == NULL){
        return -1;
    }


    for(j=1; j<size; j++){
        memcpy(key, &a[j*esize], esize);
        i = j-1;

        while(i>=0 && compare(&a[i*esize], key)>0){
            memcpy(&a[(i+1)*esize],&a[i*esize], esize);
            i--;
        }

        memcpy(&a[(i+1)*esize], key, esize);


    }
}
```

So, in the section about the complexity it states the following:

> The runtime complexity of insertion sort focuses on its nested loops.
>   With this in mind, the outer loop has a running time of T(n) = n – 1,
>   times some constant amount of time, where n is the number of elements
>   being sorted. Examining the inner loop in the worst case, we assume
>   that we will have to go all the way to the left end of the array
>   before inserting each element into the sorted set. Therefore, the
>   inner loop could iterate once for the first element, twice for the
>   second, and so forth until the outer loop terminates. The running time
>   of the nested loop is repre- sented as a summation from 1 to n – 1,
>   which results in a running time of T (n) = (n (n + 1)/2) – n, times
>   some constant amount of time. (This is from the well- known formula
>   for summing a series from 1 to n.) Using the rules of O-notation, this simplifies to O(n^2)

So, I googled the summation formula and understand why it is (n(n+1)/2). There are also a bunch of youtube videos about this formula which I also watched. 
But I could not understand the last part of T(n) in the book which is the "-n" part. **Why minus n at the end** ?

Comment: Because we start from the second element `for(j=1; ...` ? What is the running time of sorting 1 element?

Comment: `n(n+1)/2 - n == n(n-1)/2` which is equal to the sum of integral values from `1` to `n-1`.

Comment: ah, so when I replace the **n** in the formula with **n-1** then I would have: **[(n-1)((n-1)+1)/2] = (n-1)n / 2**. Ok, I can see that